# Google Identity Toolkit for Office 365 accounts

Tags: office365, google-identity-toolkit, live-sdk

I have been using the Google Identity Toolkit (for Web) successfully for quite some time, but now I have encountered a problem. I have a customer who wants to use their Microsoft Office 365 Business accounts for authentication, but I have not been able to configure GIT for this.

I have configured the GIT Service and the Identity Providers (Google, Microsoft and Yahoo) as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/required-endpoints#microsoft) and the description provided by Microsoft [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/).

One of the issues I encountered was that I had configured my application in the Microsoft Application Registration Portal as a Live SDK application (with an Application ID and a Secret). I created a new (generic?) application with other Application ID and Application Password values. After this, I updated the Client ID and the Secret Key with these values in the Identity Toolkit API on the Google Developer Console.

No luck, though. When users try to sign in to my Web application using their Office 365 Business accounts, they still get an “account does not exist” error message from the Microsoft Sign In application.

No doubt, the problem is that users are redirected to the Microsoft Live ID Sign In application (login.live.com) instead of the Microsoft Office 365 Business Sign In application (login.microsoftonline.com). But, I have no idea who is responsible for this redirect (Google Identity Toolkit, the Account Chooser, or the Microsoft endpoint). Or, how to fix this.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Identity Toolkit server generates the redirection url. Currently Live ID Sign In is the only endpoint supported for Microsoft. Office 365 Business Sign In is not supported for now.